# Difference with and without は

Tags: meaning

> あしたなにをしますか。 
>   あしたはなにをしますか。

Hi everyone!
I want to know if there is any difference in the meaning for the above sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

は defines the theme of the sentence (the subjected that is talked about) so it might add a nuance of contrast.

> 明日は何をしますか。

means "what will you do tomorrow?" in the sense of "about tomorrow, what are you going to do?".

> 明日何をしますか。

This one however just means a neutral "what will you do tomorrow?".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, for example if you were talking about what you were doing the days before, the は in 「明日は何をしますか」 can imply that you will probably do something different the day after. The same sentence without は has no such nuance.

If you want to go further, Jay Rubin's *Making Sense of Japanese* explains the は concept very clearly.